# Get text from one label on multi-label UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

On my `UITableView`I am using custom `UITableViewCell`s. Each of these cells has a number of labels. When the user selects a cell, I need to capture the contents of just *one* of these labels, but I don't know how to do that. Here is my code. The line that I am using to attempt to get this label text is basically pseudo-code that clearly won't compile. Can somebody please tell me what I need to do here? Thanks!

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ...
    Groups *group = [self.fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.groupDescriptionLabel.text = group.group_descr;
    cell.groupIDLabel.text = [group.group_id stringValue];    
    return cell;
}

- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // capture the user selection
    Groups *group = [self.fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *selection = selectedCell.groupDescriptionLabel.text;  //<-- pseudo-code

    NSLog(@"%@", group.group_descr);

    ...    
}
```

Comment: You should not be storing data in the view. You are already getting the string from your data source in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Just do the same in the `didSelectRow` code to get the string.

Comment: @Fogmeister - I like that suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: Added answer :D glad it helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's generally a bad idea to get data out of the view. You shouldn't really be using any view objects as a way of storing information.

You are already getting the string when you are in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

You should be able to do the same in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to get the same string.

That way you don't have to get the text out of the label at all.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you know that celForRowAtIndexPath is going to be returning one of your custom cell types instead of a generic UITableViewCell, cast the result to your custom cell class:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // capture the user selection
    MyCellClass *selectedCell = (MyCellClass *) [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *selection = selectedCell.groupDescriptionLabel.text;  //<-- pseudo-code
    NSLog(@"%@", selection);
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. My approach was a bit of a hack since I couldn't figure out how to get the data from the source, but another suggestion  gave me a cleaner way to do this. I appreciate the suggestion. +1 for the direct answer to my question.

Comment: Although it answers the question that was asked, it's generally not a good idea to use view elements to store information.

Comment: @Fogmeister, good point. I should have noticed that. User55410, you should really collect user input from your cells as soon as it's entered and save it in your model. Trying to collect data from the fields of your cell in tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: is bad. If the user enters data into a cell and then scrolls that cell off-screen, the data is lost.